# Create a file using ".command" file in mac

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to create a dummy file from a `.command` file. User has to double click this `.command` file which in turn should create a dummy file named "ready_to_move.trigger".

Below is the code for my `.command` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Presence of this file indicates, SFTP should happen now!" > ready_to_move.trigger;
echo "Thanks, your file upload should start in moment!";
exit;
```

However, when I double click this `.command` file, "ready_to_move.trigger" file does not get created; and I see following output in new Terminal window:

```
Akshays-MacBook-Pro:~ akshaylokur$ /Users/akshaylokur/Desktop/I_AM_DONE.command ; exit;
Thanks, your file upload should start in moment!
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

But when I run this `.command` file from Terminal (like "`./I_AM_DONE.command`", I can see "ready_to_move.trigger" file got created.

Any idea why it is happening so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission issue. When you click the application `user` is different not you and that user does not have permission to create file `ready_to_move.trigger` in that directory. Set proper permission it will resolve your problem. First provide read/write permission to all users in the directory where you are creating the trigger file and check.